# problem in put the content of h5 file into a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, nested, h5py

I have h5 file contains nested data structure as following:

Measures/Gait/Joint/Back/Abduction/Maximum
Measures/Gait/Joint/Back/Abduction/Minimum 
I am looking to put the content of nested data structure of "Minimum" and "Maximum" into Dataframe (2 columns x 25 rows).

I tried to run this code, but it doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd  
import h5py
import hdfdict

f =  h5py.File("walking5.h5",'r')

for name in f:
    print(name)

res = hdfdict.load("walking5.h5")
print(res.keys())

list3 = [['Measures']['Gait']['Joint']['Back']['Abduction']['Maximum'],['Measures']['Gait']['Joint']['Back']['Abduction']['Minimum']]

df1 = []

for np in list3:

    df = pd.DataFrame (str(res[np]))

    df.columns = [str(np)]

    df1.append(df)
```

I don't know why this code doesn't work.

I have received this error:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: Your `list3` makes no sense, what is `['Measures']['Gait']['Joint']['Back']['Abduction']['Maximum']` (the first element of the list)?

Comment: I have h5 file contains on nested data structure. To get the content of "Maximum" field I have to  ['Measures']['Gait']['Joint']['Back']['Abduction']['Maximum']

Comment: res  ['Measures']['Gait']['Joint']['Back']['Abduction']['Maximum'] = array([[5.31240405],
       [4.70486482],
       [3.32415633],
       [4.4298105 ],
       [4.87477246],
       [4.48587185],

Comment: This is an example of the content of column

Comment: I need to put the content of "Maximum" and "Minimum" field in a DataFrame contains 2 columns

Comment: If the question is not clear, i can rephrase the sentences to make it more understandable

Comment: Use a debugger and find out until which line your code runs. As @Grismar already said: `list3` is not a list. List elements need to be separated by comma

Comment: There is an error in "List3" SO if I want to take this item "['Measures']['Gait']['Joint']['Back']['Abduction']['Maximum']" and this item "['Measures']['Gait']['Joint']['Back']['Abduction']['Minimum'] in a for-loop to get the content of the nested data structure of both of them (which is one column each) by doing res ['Measures']['Gait']['Joint']['Back']['Abduction']['Maximum'] and then put these two columns in a dataframe ...How to do that?

Comment: If I understand, your list is a combination of group and dataset names. You can use this format in h5py: `'Measures/Gait/Joint/Back/Abduction/Maximum'` for a dataset name. Test with pandas. If that doesn't work, I think you need quotes to define each list element as a string: `list3 = [ "['Measures']['Gait']['Joint']['Back']['Abduction']['Maximum']", "['Measures']['Gait']['Joint']['Back']['Abduction']['Minimum']" ]`. This will create 2 list elements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have another problem I posted today on Stackoverflow. Do you like to send you the link? I need your help in solving this problem